# Should I be concerned about python 3.6 having no code signature?

Tags: macos, security, anaconda, python-3.6, network-security

[image]

I recently downloaded a program that monitors all incoming and outgoing connections and let's me assign firewall rules on the fly. It also conveniently checks the code signature of programs to verify I am not unknowingly running a modified program.

Now whenever I try to run python3.6.6, I get this little warning. Me being paranoid, I deny access and as a consequence am unable to confidently use my anaconda distribution which uses this executable.

which python --> ~/Users/me/anaconda3/bin/python

I already compared the md5 hash of the original tarball file with a new one downloaded directly from the anaconda repository and they matched.

I am not sure exactly how to proceed...
Is there a way to manually reinstall python into anaconda without using conda? Or would I be better off deleting my anaconda distribution and performing a fresh install? OR is their an alternative that is much simpler and preferred :)?

Thanks

Comment: It might help to know what this program is that you've installed.

Comment: The program giving me the alerts is called [LittleSnitch](https://www.obdev.at/products/littlesnitch/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

So I decided to backup my anaconda3 directory and them remove the entire directory which included the python3.6 in question.

I reinstalled anaconda3 with the newest release and littlesnitch reported the same suspicion, this time with python 3.7 as that was the newest version available.

[image]

This unexpected result drove me to dig deeper and following my research I came across this https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/20193 and this https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/18870.

**In summary, it is an invalid code signature, but it's also a bug.**